# Converting XML file to CSV using C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I want to convert a XML file into a CSV file using C#.

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <results>
                <results>
                        <field>2</field>
                        <something>0</something>
                        <name>alex</name>
                </results>
                <results>
                        <field>0</field>
                        <something>0</something>
                        <name>jack</name>
                </results>
                <results>
                        <field>2</field>
                        <something>1</something>
                        <name>heath</name>
                </results>
                <results>
                        <field>0</field>
                        <something>0</something>
                        <name>blake</name>
                </results>
            </results>
```

The XML above is a sample of how my file is structured, the real file is in fact much larger. I have multiple XML files and the field names change with each XML file. So I need to automatically get the field names and it's value and store it all into a CSV file. Any help would be appreciated as I'm not familiar with CSV.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no significant effort to solve the problem.

Comment: This question is too broad. First do some research and come back if you have a specific coding issue.

Comment: There's not much to be "familiar with" about CSV.  It's one record per line of text, with fields separated by commas (and, depending on the data, wrapped in double quote).  Learn a bit of XSLT and you'll have a working solution in no time.

Comment: Search for serialization/de-serialization

Comment: You can use `LINQToXML` for this purpose. Search for an example.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? can you read in the XML? Are you having issues outputting CSV?

Answer (score 1):

[Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library simplifies the process of converting any Xml to CSV files with little setup.

Using the code below you can produce Xml

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<results>
    <results>
            <field>2</field>
            <something>0</something>
            <name>alex</name>
    </results>
    <results>
            <field>0</field>
            <something>0</something>
            <name>jack</name>
    </results>
    <results>
            <field>2</field>
            <something>1</something>
            <name>heath</name>
    </results>
    <results>
            <field>0</field>
            <something>0</something>
            <name>blake</name>
    </results>
</results>";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml))
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
        w.Write(p);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output CSV:

```
field,something,name
2,0,alex
0,0,jack
2,1,heath
0,0,blake
```

Checkout CodeProject article for some additional help.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you convert your xml to csv format, but you will need to download csv reader from from [here](http://www.csvreader.com/)

```
using (CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter("users.csv"))
using (XmlRecordReader reader = new XmlRecordReader("users.xml", "users/user"))
{
reader.Columns.Add("field", "field");
reader.Columns.Add("something", "something");
reader.Columns.Add("name", "name");

writer.Write("field");
writer.Write("something");
writer.Write("name");
writer.EndRecord();

while (reader.ReadRecord())
{
    writer.Write(reader["field"]);
    writer.Write(reader["something"]);
    writer.Write(reader["name"]);
    writer.EndRecord();
}
reader.Close();
writer.Close();
}
```